# Why are microwave oven transformer laminations not insulated?

Tags: transformer, high-voltage

I know that it is a peculiarly designed transformer, but I never found any explanation (and nor even questions) about that before.

I know that soldering the lamination in the edges for instance won't increase the losses in the core significantly, but what I didn't see anyone commenting is that it seems they aren't even insulated.

Or at least not in a couple MOTs I've dismantled. They're bare metal, they have no insulating layer between them.

Shouldn't that cause the core to be much more lossy?

Comment: Why transformer core made from pieces, not solid? Make no sense. They are insulated.

Comment: There is nothing peculiar in the microwave oven transformer, except for the intermittent duty rating. Run it for 20' and you get the transformer smell.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> *They're bare metal, they have no insulating layer between them.*

In short, natural oxides on the surface formed by the manufacturing process are good candidates for producing insulation properties: -

[image]

Information about natural insulating (or semi insulating) oxides taken from [**this website**](https://www.edcorusa.com/core-steel). Can you tell by looking that they are bare metal - are you eyes (or anyone's) capable of seeing this?

Comment: Not only it looks bare metal, but measuring it with a ohmmeter also accuses it's conductive, there's why I thought it was bare. Maybe there's a thin oxide layer in there, but it isn't insulating even a few volts then.

Comment: It’s easy to break through an oxide layer with multimeter probes that are sharp. Do you see the oxide layer on the surface of stainless steel that gives it its shine?

Comment: @user2934303 if you are done with this question now you should accept an answer as per site etiquette. [Take the tour in 2 minutes](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/tour) explains how this is done. Of course, if you have residual queries relating to this question you should leave a comment.

Comment: I found your answer here, from another one provided by Russel about Microwave transformer. My question to you is related to the welding closing fixture employed in most microwave transformers, but I saw this being on other ones for different applications. My *question* then is related to further know about any potential traders of doing this. Thanks.

Comment: @EJE this isn't how this site works i.e. you need to raise a new question AND you'll probably get several responses and better answers than in comments.

Answer (score 2):

Inside the core the energy is magnetic flux rather than current; what would appear as a very poor electrical insulator can be an effective insulator against eddy currents.

Comment: And microwave ovens are cheap-cheap-cheap.  So the process will be optimized for just good enough and minimal expenditure -- not the world's best transformer.